# SwiftUI - ScrollView: onChange -> scrollTo cuts off text

Tags: swift, swiftui

Currently, I have a ScrollView with this code:

```
ScrollView {
    ScrollViewReader { scrollView in
        VStack {
            ForEach(messages, id: \.id) { message in
                MessageView(message)
            }
            MessageInput()
        }
        .onChange(of: messages.count) { _ in
            scrollView.scrollTo(messages.last.id)
        }
        .onAppear { scrollView.scrollTo(messages.last.id) }
    }
}
```

`.onAppear()` works as intended, giving this view:
[image: .onAppear Image]
However, when I send a new message and `.onChange` is called, I get this:
[image: .onChange appearance]

`MessageView()` does have padding, but I don't see how that would affect it only `.onChange` and not `.onAppear`.

How can I move the view down so that the message input box is included?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want input be inside scroller then, probably, you need something like the following

```
ScrollView {
    ScrollViewReader { scrollView in
        VStack {
            ForEach(messages, id: \.id) { message in
                MessageView(message)
            }
            MessageInput().id("input")
        }
        .onChange(of: messages.count) { _ in
            scrollView.scrollTo("input", anchor: .bottom)
        }
        .onAppear { 
            scrollView.scrollTo("input", anchor: .bottom)
        }
    }
}
```