# swiftui scrollto doesn't scroll all the way

Tags: swiftui

So this is interesting/infuriating. Using the scrollTo inside an onChange or onAppear doesn't scroll ALL the way to the bottom of the list leaving some of the last row hidden. Weirdly when I click on a Button with the same scrollTo line it works fine (see code), but when the scrollTo is inside a onChange or onAppear it won't work. (the second image is AFTER I click the button)

EDIT: One observation is that no matter how tall I make the VStack inside the list items the scrollTo inside the onChange event always scrolls to the height of a standard height row (resulting in hiding the bottom). It seems its not taking into account the height of the row item.

Here is my code:

```
        VStack {
        Button("Scroll To ") {
            readerProxy?.scrollTo(careLogItems.last)
        }
        ScrollViewReader { reader in
            List(careLogItems) { i in
                VStack {
                    Text(i.logText)
                    Text(i.logDate.description)
                }.id(i)
            }.onAppear {
                readerProxy = reader
                //reader.scrollTo(careLogItems.last)
            }
            CareLogItemDetail(careLogItem: $newCareLogItem, addItem: addCareLogItem)
        }
    }
    .onChange(of: careLogItems) { _ in
        print("changed \(careLogItems.count)")
        readerProxy?.scrollTo(careLogItems.last)
    }
    .onAppear {
        if (hasAppeared == false) {
            hasAppeared = true
            loadCareLogItems()
        }
    }
```

[image: scroll to doesn't reach bottom]

[image]

Comment: So the order of events is: `careLogItems` changes -> at the same time: `onChange` triggers _and_ `List` starts to rearrange itself. So you have a race condition between `List` finishing its update for new item, and `onChange` trying to navigate to the bottom. And my guess is `onChange` is always faster. As a test (not as a design idea!) try to delay `readerProxy?.scrollTo` inside `onChange by, say, 0.3-0.5 sec. If it fixes the issue - that's it. And if so, you may need to buffer scrolling so that UI has a chance to complete update

Comment: @timbretimbre ... yes i was thinking the same as you. So I added: "DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 3.0) {
                readerProxy?.scrollTo(careLogItems.last)
            }" do delay the execution for 3 secs but still the same issue.

Comment: Ok...this guy is onto something: https://marcpalmer.net/is-your-swiftui-scrollview-scrolling-to-the-wrong-location-in-ios-15/

Comment: Looks like a similar issue as this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65987088/swiftui-scrollview-onchange-scrollto-cuts-off-text

Comment: This is what worked for me: proxy.scrollTo(p.sequence, anchor: .top)